# Remove unselected items from the array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I developed an autocomplete dropdown.

When I select users, I store the ID's in the users array.

When I select a user it is added to the array, but when unselected the user, is there a way to remove it from the array? How can I do this?

Is there also a way to convert the array to a string, in order to output a string, example: "1,2"?

Thanks

[**Stackblitz - demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yr8pdh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**.ts**

```
users:any [] =[];
 itemSelectionChanged(e){
   console.log("item",e)
   if(e.itemData.selected == true){
     this.users.push(e.itemData.ID);
     console.log(this.users)

     //output as a string and not an array.... like "1,2"
   }
   else{
     //Remove the unselected value in the array this.users e.itemData.ID
   }
 }
```

**.html**

```
<dx-drop-down-box [(value)]="treeBoxValue" valueExpr="ID" displayExpr="name" placeholder="Select a value..."
    [showClearButton]="true" [dataSource]="treeDataSource" (onValueChanged)="syncTreeViewSelection()">
    <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'content'">
        <dx-tree-view [dataSource]="treeDataSource" dataStructure="plain" selectionMode="multiple"
            showCheckBoxesMode="normal" [selectNodesRecursive]="false" displayExpr="name" [searchEnabled]="true"
            [selectByClick]="true" (onItemSelectionChanged)="itemSelectionChanged($event)">
        </dx-tree-view>
    </div>
</dx-drop-down-box>
```

[image]

Comment: here is a [blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2z4cno) with the display and filtering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` to remove the item from the array. You can use `Array.prototype.join` to combine the array elements with a separator such as a comma character:

```
  itemSelectionChanged(e) {
    // Use object destructure to get property `ID`
    const { ID } = e.itemData;
    if (e.itemData.selected) {
      // Check if element is in array so a duplicate is not added
      // Note: this only works with primitive values, not objects
      if (this.users.indexOf(ID) < 0) {
        this.users.push(ID);
      }

      // Join array items with comma character
      console.log(this.users.join(","));
    } else {
      // Remove items using filter
      this.users = this.users.filter(user => user !== ID);
    }
  }
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qgv6em) in action.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, copy in else statement `this.users=this.users.filter(x=>x!=e.itemData.ID);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `splice` array function to remove the element from your array. See the below code.

```
itemSelectionChanged(e) {
    console.log("item",e)
    if(e.itemData.selected == true){
        this.users.push(e.itemData.ID);
        console.log(this.users.join());
        //output as a string and not an array.... like "1,2"
    } else {
        const indexOfRemovedElementID = this.users.indexOf(e.itemData.ID);
        this.users.splice(indexOfRemovedElementID, 1);
        console.log(this.users.join());
        //Remove the unselected value in the array this.users e.itemData.ID
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `filter()`, you could also use [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) with `indexOf()` to remove items from array. Include the following in the `else` block

```js
const index = this.users.indexOf(e.itemData.ID, 0);
if (index > -1) {
  this.users.splice(index, 1);
}
```

I've extended your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hpmhov).

Difference between `filter()` and `splice()` is while `filter()` returns a new array, `splice()` modifies the array in place. So if you use `filter()`, it needs to assigned back to the variable like `this.users = this.users.filter(...)`, while `splice()` does not require back assignment.